# Converting unicode characters through javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have retrieved the following text (some of them are Chinese characters) from php script as the select options, but unable to turn them into readable characters (whether through php or javascript), please advice.

```
\\xe8\\xac\\x9b\\xe5\\x91\\xa2D\\xe3\\x80\\x82
```

Comment: To do this, first you must know what transformation the characters are in. The above don't seem to be UTF-16 (either LE or BE; if they were, this would be straightforward). So that's the first thing.

Comment: Can you tell what should be the result ?

Comment: The right string should be "講呢D。"

Comment: http://mothereff.in/utf-8#%E8%AC%9B%E5%91%A2D%E3%80%82

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input = '\xe8\xac\x9b\xe5\x91\xa2D\xe3\x80\x82'
console.log(decodeURIComponent(escape(input)))
```

This gives you exactly

```
講呢D。
```

UPDATE

If your string really contains `\x` characters, then we can convert them to `%`s first:

```
input = '\\xe8\\xac\\x9b\\xe5\\x91\\xa2D\\xe3\\x80\\x82'

decodeURIComponent(input.replace(/\\x/g, '%'))
```

Comment: I still cannot get it right, but can see the right characters through browser's console
http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2013/12/20/000.jpg

Comment: Million thanks, finally, I got it right!! Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 1):

While [@punund's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702337/1249581) is correct, it is also possible to make bytes to UTF conversion manually.

In the Unicode char map Chinese characters occupy 3 bytes in the range 00000800 — 0000FFFF, hence your string of bytes should be grouped by three and transformed to the real UTF characters.

Here is one possible solution:

```
var str = '\\xe8\\xac\\x9b\\xe5\\x91\\xa2D\\xe3\\x80\\x82',
    result = str.replace(/(\\{1,2}x[0-9a-f]{2}){3}/g, function(c) {
        var u = eval('"' + c + '"');
        return String.fromCharCode(
             ((u.charCodeAt(0) & 15) << 12) |
             ((u.charCodeAt(1) & 63) << 6) |
              (u.charCodeAt(2) & 63));
    });

console.log(result);   // "講呢D。"
```

**N.B.:** while using `eval` is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21), in the provided example it is completely harmless.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have learnt much from the thread :)